# Trying to make a subquery with three tables

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm using the following query to let users search for an order:

```
SELECT orders.*, tasks_x.task_all
        FROM orders LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tasks.task_name SEPARATOR ",")
            AS task_all, ordertasks.id_order 
                FROM tasks JOIN ordertasks 
                on ordertasks.id_task = tasks.id GROUP BY ordertasks.id_order) as tasks_x
                ON tasks_x.id_order = orders.id WHERE orders.order_name 
                LIKE "%keyword%" OR tasks_x.task_all LIKE "%keyword%"
```

They can search an order through a order name or a task name that is linked to a order that they were searching for. But now I want also that they can search an order through a company name.

Here is my clients table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtDS3.png

And here are my other tables if you need them:

orders:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjTjD.png

ordertasks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRBve.png

tasks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNNLq.png

I have also put the query and my tables on sqlfiddle here is the link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d942/2

To be actually honest I had received help from my internship supervisor to create the sub query that you find above. So I don't know how to achieve this. I think I know how to do this with joins, but not with subqueries. But I gladly want to know it how this can be achieved with a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relation between orders to (task or ordertasks) is 1:1 then this query should do the trick with no subqueries

```
SELECT o.*, t.task_name
FROM orders AS o
LEFT JOIN clients AS c ON c.id = o.id_client
LEFT JOIN ordertasks AS x on x.id_order = o.id
LEFT JOIN tasks AS t ON t.id = x.id_order
WHERE o.order_name LIKE "%keyword%" 
OR t.task_name LIKE "%keyword%" 
OR c.companyName LIKE "%keyword%";
```

If the relation between orders to (task or ordertasks) is 1:n where n can be greater than 1 then this query should do the trick

```
SELECT c.companyName, x.task_all, o.*
FROM orders AS o 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.task_name) AS task_all, x.id_order 
    FROM tasks AS t
    INNER JOIN ordertasks AS x on x.id_task = t.id
    WHERE t.task_name LIKE "%wau%"
    GROUP BY x.id_order
) AS x ON x.id_order = o.id
LEFT JOIN clients AS c ON c.id = o.id_client
WHERE o.order_name LIKE "%wau%" 
OR x.id_order IS NOT NULL
OR c.companyName LIKE "%wau%"
```

**Note:** I do not agree with using LIKE operation to find records because `LIKE "%keyword%"`will use no indexes "this mean MySQL will do a whole table scan every time "per table". Trying to search using LIKE will be very slow if you have lots of records in the tables

to improve the speed you can use Full-Text Index on the columns and then use `MATCH() AGAINST()` logic to search for the records instead of using `LIKE`

If you want to go that route then you would have do the the following

1. add FULLTEXT INDEX on orders.order_name
2. add FULLTEXT INDEX on task.task_name
3. add FULLTEXT INDEX on clients.companyName

Here are the queries that you would have to run

```
ALTER TABLE orders ADD FULLTEXT INDEX order_name (order_name);
ALTER TABLE tasks ADD FULLTEXT INDEX task_name (task_name);
ALTER TABLE tasks ADD FULLTEXT INDEX company_name (companyName);
```

Then the first query will be something like this

```
SELECT o.*, t.task_name
FROM orders AS o
LEFT JOIN clients AS c ON c.id = o.id_client
LEFT JOIN ordertasks AS x on x.id_order = o.id
LEFT JOIN tasks AS t ON t.id = x.id_order
WHERE MATCH('keyword') AGAINST(o.order_name)
OR MATCH('keyword') AGAINST(t.task_name)
OR MATCH('keyword') AGAINST(c.companyName);
```

The second option will be something like this

```
SELECT c.companyName, x.task_all, o.*
FROM orders AS o 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.task_name) AS task_all, x.id_order 
    FROM tasks AS t
    INNER JOIN ordertasks AS x on x.id_task = t.id
    WHERE MATCH('wau') AGAINST(t.task_name)
    GROUP BY x.id_order
) AS x ON x.id_order = o.id
LEFT JOIN clients AS c ON c.id = o.id_client
WHERE o.order_name LIKE "%wau%" 
OR x.id_order IS NOT NULL
OR c.companyName LIKE "%wau%"
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but I think that you are using joins only. I gladly want to see how it's done with a subquery. Also what do you mean with "it also d" :) ?

Comment: sorry it seems that my answer was cut at the end. I updated my answer. Why would you need sub queries? are there multiple tasks per order in the database?

Comment: One more thought, if you only want to return columns from the orders table we can tweek the query even more to make it more efficient. We can use exists logic to check if a match is found instead of using joins.

Comment: Hi your subquery works :), but why do you use 'IS NOT NULL' in the first subquery? Because the query still let me show the order that has been found. Also thanks for sharing the fulltext queries, I couldn't run them because of my MySQL engine. I think I need a MyISAM Engine to do Full-Text search. But I will test it tomorrow, because now I'm tired.

Comment: I am glad they query helped you. You should be able to use the full-text index. You can use FT indexes on innodb tables. Regarding the IS NOT NULL, what I did to make your query perform better, I moved the `t.task_name LIKE "%wau%"` to the sub query. This will reduce the data set that is being returned in the sub query. Therefore, if a record found in the task_name you want to return it. The query will look for anything that is found in `orders.task_name` table and anything that is found in `clients.companyNames`. And also we look for any records the the sub query found. I hope this helps.